# How to dynamically wrap Primefaces component in a div?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to dynamically enclosed Primefaces component in a `<div>` tag. Is this possible?

Example using

```
<p:inputText />
```

will be rendered as:

```
<div>
<input id="j_idt18" ...>
</div>
```

I tried creating a custom component extending PF's InputText and in the renderer I manually enclosed InputText markup like:

```
@Override
protected void encodeMarkup(FacesContext context,
        org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputText inputText)
        throws IOException {

    ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
    String clientId = div.getClientId(context);
    writer.startElement("div", div);

    super.encodeMarkup(context, inputText);
    writer.endElement("div");

    }
```

It's working fine however when I do an ajax update on the InputText component, the div is rerendered and recreated again. How do I prevent the div from being rerendered in the markup?

I can't use composite component only custom component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your input in `<h:panelGroup layout="block">`:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block">
    <p:inputText />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper composite component, say `<my:inputText>`, expose the properties of `<p:inputText>` via the component's argument list and inside the components wrap the `<p:pinputText>` inside a `<div>`. Then use the custom component `<my:inputText>` everywhere instead of `<p:inputText>`